# I want filter to JSON data using Angular 5 services, but filtering should be done on server level (Live Search)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6, livesearch

I know there's a concept of pipes, but for pipes to work it should have all the data.

I am using Angular Services

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Patient } from '../shared/patient';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class PatientService {

 private serviceUrl = 'someUrl';

  private patients = new BehaviorSubject<Patient[]>(null);
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      this.http.get<Patient[]>(this.serviceUrl);
    // .subscribe(data => { console.log(data); });
    }
  /*
   * Get list of all patients
  */
    getPatient(): Observable<Patient[]> {
        return this.http.get<Patient[]>(this.serviceUrl);
   }

   selectPatient(patients: Patient[]) {
     this.patients.next(patients);
     // return this.patients.asObservable;
   }
   getSelectedPatient(): Observable<Patient[]> {
     return this.patients.asObservable();
   }
}
```

This is where all "Searching" Takes Place:

```
        <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="check-all" (click)="checkall()"></th>
                <th>Patient Name</th>
                <th>Patient ID</th>
                <th>NHS</th>
                <th>MPI</th>
                <th>HID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let patient of patients | patientFilter:filter; let i = index" [class.active]="i == selectedRow">
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" (click)="uncheckall();"></td>
                <td>{{ patient.firstName }} {{ patient.middleName }} {{patient.lastName}}</td>
                <td>{{ patient.pid }}</td>
                <td>{{ patient.nhs }}</td>
                <td>{{ patient.mpi }}</td>
                <td>{{ patient.hid }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is the method which I am using in typescript file which will get all the patients list when html page is loaded:

```
ngOnInit() {
            this.patientService.getPatient().subscribe(
            (patients: Patient[]) => { this.patients = patients;});
        }
```

Is there any efficient way/method to apply filter?

Comment: Can you should your server code as well?

Comment: there's no server side code. I am fetching the JSON data from the url and using it on ngOnInit() method @KelvinLai